# Widget's didUpdateWidget method called when screen rotates with MaterialApp routes

Tags: dart, flutter

When I use `routes` in `MaterialApp` the child widget's (`MyHomePage`) `didUpdateWidget` is called whenever I rotate the screen/open the keyboard etc.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      routes: {
        '/': (_) => MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
      },
      initialRoute: '/',
    );
  }
}
```

On the other hand, when I use the `home` parameter, `didUpdateWidget` is not called when I rotate the screen/open the keyboard.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}
```

The issue I have is that I am using the [Bloc pattern sample](https://github.com/filiph/state_experiments/blob/master/shared/lib/src/bloc_complex/product_grid/product_square.dart) as a guide so my Bloc is disposed and recreated whenever the `didUpdateWidget` is called. This means I lose all my app's state that is in the Bloc, e.g. what is selected.

```
@override
void didUpdateWidget(ProductSquare oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
    _disposeBloc();
    _createBloc();
}
```

Why is there a difference is behavior between using `routes` and `home`? How can I make `routes` behave like `home` and not call `didUpdateWidget` when the screen is rotated so the bloc is not unnecessarily recreated?

Full app sample without Bloc that rebuilds whenever I rotate the screen.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      routes: {
        '/': (_) => MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
      },
      initialRoute: '/',
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(MyHomePage oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);

    print('didUpdateWidget');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> The issue I have is that I am using the Bloc pattern sample as a guide so my Bloc is disposed and recreated whenever the didUpdateWidget is called. This means I lose all my app's state that is in the Bloc, e.g. what is selected.

This is the problem. Don't do that, it is an anti-pattern.

Any widgets you make should keep in mind that they can theoretically be updated thousands of times with no changes. You're supposed to verify that something changed before performing side-effects.

As such your `didUpdateWidget` should be as followed:

```
@override
void didUpdateWidget(ProductSquare oldWidget) {
  super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
  if (widget.product != oldWidget.product) {
    _disposeBloc();
    _createBloc();
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain why there's calls to `didUpdateWidget` when using routes, but the exact code with `home` doesn't call `didUpdateWidget`? Doesn't this mean the parent widget (i.e. the entire app) is being rebuilt unnecessarily often instead of just some of the widgets in the tree.

To me it doesn't make sense that there can be such as substantial difference in rebuilds by just switching from routes to the `home` parameter of the `MaterialApp`.

Comment: `routes` are functions called whenever something in `Navigator` changes while `home` is "constant".

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is there any performance issues called by the extra calls to `didUpdateWidget`? I noticed that `didUpdateWidget` evens gets called when a WebView opens or the keyboard opens when using `routes`.

Comment: No it's fine. Widgets are made to be updated frequently

Comment: Hey, I think this is one of the actual developers of Flutter